# Pipe Unix commands together with C

Tags: c, unix, exec, pipe

I want to simulate this Unix command :

```
cat file.txt | sort | tail -4
```

I followed the technique, but it does not work, it remains blocked.
Maybe i need to use something else when there are files.
I used two pipes, and two processes and i used two DUP in a single process, maybe that's wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
  int p1[2];
  int p2[2];

  if(pipe(p1))
  {
    perror("pipe1");
    exit(0);
  }

  if(pipe(p2))
  {
    perror("pipe2");
    exit(0);
  }

  switch(fork())
  {
    case -1: perror(" fork1 error ");
             exit(0);

    case  0: close(STDOUT_FILENO);
             (void)dup(p1[1]);
             close(p1[1]);
             close(p1[0]);
             execlp("cat", "cat", "file.txt", NULL);
             exit(0);
    default: 
            switch(fork())
            {
              case -1: perror(" fork2 error ");
               exit(0);

              case  0: close(STDIN_FILENO);
                       (void)dup(p1[0]);
                       close(p1[1]);
                       close(p1[0]);

                       close(STDOUT_FILENO);
                       (void)dup(p2[1]);
                       close(p2[1]);
                       close(p2[0]);

                       execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);
                       exit(0);

              default: 
                       wait(NULL);
                       close(STDIN_FILENO);
                       (void)dup(p2[0]);
                       close(p2[0]);
                       close(p2[1]);
                       execlp("tail", "tail", "-4", NULL); 
            }             
  }
}
```

this is the file.txt :

```
g
f
d
b
c
a
e
```

Comment: Unless you're doing this to learn, I'd suggest using libpipline -- http://libpipeline.nongnu.org/

Comment: Why do you call wait(3)?

Comment: To until the end of the two process

Comment: I found the solution. The problem is i'm not closing the pipes as i should.

Comment: You'll probably want dup2() instead of dup().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent process never closes the pipe `p1` so its child keep trying to read on it. Add `close(p1[0]); close(p1[1]);` before the `execlp("tail", "tail", "-4", NULL);`.

Also note that you should *not* `wait(NULL)`: this is another hang waiting to happen when file.txt is big and starts to fill the pipe buffer.